# InteliJ doesn't run javafx applications: exit code -1073740791

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using IntelliJ-IDEA 2016.3, and I'm having some problems running my javafx applications. Without any log messages or errors, I am always getting

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

when attempting to run even the most simplest of applications.

For example, this is my main class

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

with the complementary fxml file:

```
    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
              xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10"                 vgap="10">
    </GridPane>
```

Keep in mind this is the most basic example.
I just switched my machine, and perhaps i have forgotten some extra configs..?

Comment: Could you please give some more information on what system/software you're using? E.g. are you using Windows/Linux, which Distribution, Oracle JDK/OpenJDK, Java version etc.

Comment: I'm using win 10 education, 64 bit, OracleJDK, 1.8

Comment: TL;DR - try updating or else downgrading your nvidia driver.